# Вывод всех значений HashMap

Tags: java

Добрый день. Программа должна выдавать ключ и несколько значений по этому ключу, но значения выводятся в виде кода:
 [{Person@1b6d3586=[Phone@4554617c, Phone@74a14482]}]
Как вывести в стандартном виде?

```
public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Person, List<Phone>> personPhone = new HashMap<Person, List<Phone>>();
        personPhone.put(new Person("Иван", "Иванов"), Arrays.asList(new Phone(88002000500L), new Phone(88002000500L)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(personPhone));

    }
}

class Phone {
    public long numberPhone;

    public Phone(long numberPhone) {
        this.numberPhone = numberPhone;
    }
}

class Person {
    public String name;
    public String lastName;

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас не переопределен метод toString(а так же hasdCode и equals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В класс `Person` и `Phone` добавить метод `toString()`

Person:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "Person [name=" + name + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
}
```

Phone:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "Phone [numberPhone=" + numberPhone + "]";
}
```

Или обработайте Map циклом:

```
for (Entry<Person, List<Phone>> entry : personPhone.entrySet()) {
    Person person = entry.getKey();
    List<Phone> phones = entry.getValue();
    ... Распечатываем удобным способом
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
personPhone.entrySet().forEach(
   entry -> entry.getValue().forEach(
       phone -> {
           Person person = entry.getKey();
           System.out.println(person.name + " " + person.lastName + " " + phone.numberPhone);
       }
    )
);
```